# how can i mock createBottomTabNavigator from @react-navigation/bottom-tabs in Jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I can't seem to be able to test my bottom navigator with Jest.

here's my navigator :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import IonIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import HomeNavigator from './routes/home';
import SearchNavigator from './routes/search';

export default function Navigator() {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        tabBarOptions={{
          keyboardHidesTabBar: true,
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeNavigator}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
              <Icon name="home" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Search"
          component={SearchNavigator}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Search',
            tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
              <IonIcon
                name="search"
                color={color}
                size={size}
                style={{transform: [{scaleX: -1}]}}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

*navigation/index.js*

my redux wrapper component's render function:

```
<Provider store={global.store}>
  <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={global.persistor}>
    {this.props.children}
  </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

*redux_wrapper.js*

My navigator.test.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {render, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import ReduxWrapper from '../src/redux/redux_wrapper';

import HomeNavigator from '../src/navigation/routes/home';

jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper');

describe('Testing react navigation', () => {
  test('page contains the header and 10 items', async () => {
    const component = (
      <ReduxWrapper>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <HomeNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </ReduxWrapper>
    );

    const {getAllByTestId} = render(component);

    const homeScene = getAllByTestId('homeScene');

    expect(homeScene).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

*navigator.test.js*

when i try to run it , i get the following error from **Jest**:
[image]

how can i test this correctly , knowing that my main intention here is to test the navigation to a details screen later on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getByTestID` function looks at the `testID=` attributes of the rendered components.

You've not shared the code for `HomeNavigator` but if you change it to something like:

```html
// './routes/home'
    <View testID="homeScene">
      { /* rest of the HomeNavigator code */ }
    </View>
```

You might also need to set the `initialRouteName` attribute in your `<Tab.Navigator` JSX.

```html
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        tabBarOptions={{
          keyboardHidesTabBar: true,
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen
        ...
      </Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Thanks , that did it. I actually had a typo in the testID i was passing.